# Few connections failed when downloading packages

Tags: raspbian, packages, raspbian-stretch

I am working with Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch for a project that involves image processing (Open CV and Dlib). I am very inexperienced with Linux systems and having a hard time with installing packages since some parts of the packages are not being downloaded and says connection failed while others are downloaded and I assume it thus doesn't install the package or is broken.

I assume there is something wrong with the repository since almost every 'sudo ap-get install' or 'sudo apt-get upgrade' are returning few connection failed messages. I don't know how to change it to a repository that has the right packages and also I am unable to figure out which repository will have those files and be compatible with Raspbian Stretch.

This is the log file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
gstreamer1.0-omx
The following packages will be upgraded:
apt apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host bluez curl dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 desktop-base dhcpcd5 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 git git-man gnupg gnupg-agent gpgv libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0
libatspi2.0-0 libavcodec57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbind9-140 libbluetooth3 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdb5.3 libdbus-1-3 libdns-export162 libdns162 libfm-data
libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk4 libfm-modules libfm4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libidn2-0 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblwres141 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnss3 libperl5.24 libpostproc54 libruby2.3 libsmbclient
libswresample2 libswscale4 libtinfo5 libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxfont2 linux-libc-dev lxpanel lxpanel-data lxplug-bluetooth lxplug-ejecter lxplug-network lxplug-volume ncurses-base ncurses-bin
ncurses-term pcmanfm perl perl-base perl-modules-5.24 pigpio python-jwt python-pigpio python-pip python-pip-whl python3-jwt python3-pigpio python3-pip raspi-config raspi-copies-and-fills
realvnc-vnc-server realvnc-vnc-viewer rpi-chromium-mods ruby2.3 samba-common samba-libs scratch2 vim-common vim-tiny wpasupplicant xkb-data xserver-common xserver-xorg-core xxd
106 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.3 MB/154 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,045 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf rpi-chromium-mods armhf 20171017
Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libbluetooth3 armhf 5.43-2+rpt1+deb9u1
Connection failed [IP: 46.235.227.11 80]
Err:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf realvnc-vnc-server armhf 6.2.0.29523
Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.214 80]
Err:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libkrb5support0 armhf 1.15-1+deb9u1
Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libwbclient0 armhf 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2
Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gnupg-agent armhf 2.1.18-8~deb9u1
Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
90% [Waiting for headers]
```

another log file when trying to install TightVncServer

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  xfonts-base
Suggested packages:
  tightvnc-java
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  realvnc-vnc-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tightvncserver xfonts-base
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 106 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,911 kB/6,461 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf xfonts-base all 1:1.0.4+nmu1
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xfonts-base/xfonts-base_1.0.4+nmu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

BTW I am using SSH via PuTTY to access my Raspberry Pi 3 and it was a headless install. Tried to download numerous things like GTK library but almost everything was partially downloaded like following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [1                                                                                                                               1.7 MB]
Fetched 11.7 MB in 1min 53s (103 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gstreamer1.0-omx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host bluez curl dbus
  dbus-user-session dbus-x11 desktop-base dhcpcd5 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 git
  git-man gnupg gnupg-agent gpgv libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libatspi2.0-0
  libavcodec57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55
  libbind9-140 libbluetooth3 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdb5.3 libdbus-1-3
  libdns-export162 libdns162 libfm-data libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk4
  libfm-modules libfm4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgnutls30
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libidn2-0 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140
  libisccfg140 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblwres141 libncurses5
  libncursesw5 libnss3 libperl5.24 libpostproc54 libruby2.3 libsmbclient
  libswresample2 libswscale4 libtinfo5 libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libxfont2 linux-libc-dev lxpanel lxpanel-data lxplug-bluetooth
  lxplug-ejecter lxplug-network lxplug-volume ncurses-base ncurses-bin
  ncurses-term pcmanfm perl perl-base perl-modules-5.24 pigpio python-jwt
  python-pigpio python-pip python-pip-whl python3-jwt python3-pigpio
  python3-pip raspi-config raspi-copies-and-fills realvnc-vnc-server
  realvnc-vnc-viewer rpi-chromium-mods ruby2.3 samba-common samba-libs
  scratch2 vim-common vim-tiny wpasupplicant xkb-data xserver-common
  xserver-xorg-core xxd
106 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 154 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,045 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf ncurses-bin                                                                                                                                armhf 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [361 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libperl5.24                                                                                                                                armhf 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 [2,831 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf rpi-chromium-mods a                                                                                                                               rmhf 20171017
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.230 80]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf bluez armhf 5.43-                                                                                                                               2+rpt1+deb9u1 [722 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf perl armhf                                                                                                                                5.24.1-3+deb9u2 [218 kB]
Get:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf perl-base a                                                                                                                               rmhf 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 [1,197 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf dhcpcd5 armhf 1:6                                                                                                                               .11.5-1+rpt2 [135 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf perl-module                                                                                                                               s-5.24 all 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 [2,724 kB]
Err:9 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libbluetooth3 arm                                                                                                                               hf 5.43-2+rpt1+deb9u1
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
Get:10 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm-data all 1.2                                                                                                                               .5-1+rpi2 [234 kB]
Get:11 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libdb5.3 a                                                                                                                               rmhf 5.3.28-12+deb9u1 [569 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm-extra4 armhf                                                                                                                                1.2.5-1+rpi2 [29.2 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm-gtk-data all                                                                                                                                1.2.5-1+rpi2 [33.9 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm-gtk4 armhf 1                                                                                                                               .2.5-1+rpi2 [133 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf ncurses-ba                                                                                                                               se all 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [238 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libapt-pkg                                                                                                                               5.0 armhf 1.4.8 [833 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm4 armhf 1.2.5                                                                                                                               -1+rpi2 [101 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf libfm-modules armh                                                                                                                               f 1.2.5-1+rpi2 [45.8 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxpanel armhf 0.9.                                                                                                                               3-1+rpi4 [187 kB]
Get:20 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libapt-ins                                                                                                                               t2.0 armhf 1.4.8 [190 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxpanel-data all 0                                                                                                                               .9.3-1+rpi4 [1,050 kB]
Get:22 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf apt armhf                                                                                                                                1.4.8 [1,190 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxplug-bluetooth a                                                                                                                               rmhf 0.4 [15.9 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxplug-ejecter arm                                                                                                                               hf 0.3 [9,076 B]
Get:25 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxplug-network arm                                                                                                                               hf 0.5 [28.4 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf lxplug-volume armh                                                                                                                               f 0.7 [15.5 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf pcmanfm armhf 1.2.                                                                                                                               5-3+rpi2 [270 kB]
Get:28 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf apt-utils                                                                                                                                armhf 1.4.8 [392 kB]
Get:29 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gpgv armhf                                                                                                                                2.1.18-8~deb9u1 [440 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf pigpio armhf 1.6                                                                                                                               4-1 [193 kB]
Get:31 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf desktop-ba                                                                                                                               se all 9.0.2+deb9u1 [3,507 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python-pigpio al                                                                                                                               l 1.64-1 [33.5 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python3-pip all                                                                                                                                9.0.1-2+rpt1 [142 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python-pip all 9                                                                                                                               .0.1-2+rpt1 [179 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python-pip-whl a                                                                                                                               ll 9.0.1-2+rpt1 [1,399 kB]
Get:36 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf git-man al                                                                                                                               l 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2 [1,432 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python3-pigpio a                                                                                                                               ll 1.64-1 [33.5 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf raspi-copies-and                                                                                                                               -fills armhf 0.6 [7,226 B]
Get:39 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgnutls3                                                                                                                               0 armhf 3.5.8-5+deb9u3 [823 kB]
Err:40 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf realvnc-vnc-serv                                                                                                                               er armhf 6.2.0.29523
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]
Get:41 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf realvnc-vnc-view                                                                                                                               er armhf 6.17.731.29523 [2,112 kB]
Get:42 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgssapi-                                                                                                                               krb5-2 armhf 1.15-1+deb9u1 [131 kB]
Get:43 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libkrb5-3                                                                                                                                armhf 1.15-1+deb9u1 [262 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf xserver-common all 2:1.19.2-1+rpt1+deb9u2 [2,059 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf xserver-xorg-core armhf 2:1.19.2-1+rpt1+deb9u2 [3,120 kB]
Err:46 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libkrb5support0 armhf 1.15-1+deb9u1
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:47 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libk5crypto3 armhf 1.15-1+deb9u1 [115 kB]
Get:48 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libidn2-0 armhf 0.16-1+deb9u1 [59.5 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf raspi-config all 20170926 [18.8 kB]
Get:50 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libldap-2.4-2 armhf 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1 [195 kB]
Get:51 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf scratch2 armhf 0.17 [67.8 MB]
Get:52 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libldap-common all 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1 [85.4 kB]
Get:53 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libcurl3-gnutls armhf 7.52.1-5+deb9u1 [259 kB]
Get:54 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf git armhf 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2 [3,380 kB]
Err:55 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libwbclient0 armhf 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:56 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libsmbclient armhf 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2 [143 kB]
Get:57 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba-libs armhf 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2 [4,383 kB]
Get:58 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba-common all 2:4.5.12+dfsg-2 [172 kB]
Get:59 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libncurses5 armhf 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [73.9 kB]
Get:60 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libtinfo5 armhf 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [288 kB]
Get:61 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libncursesw5 armhf 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [93.3 kB]
Err:62 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gnupg-agent armhf 2.1.18-8~deb9u1
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:63 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gnupg armhf 2.1.18-8~deb9u1 [1,019 kB]
Get:64 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf vim-tiny armhf 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 [339 kB]
Get:65 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf xxd armhf 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 [131 kB]
Get:66 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf vim-common all 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 [159 kB]
Get:67 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf bind9-host armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [230 kB]
Get:68 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libisc160 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [366 kB]
Get:69 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libdns162 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [952 kB]
Get:70 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libisccc140 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [196 kB]
Get:71 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libisccfg140 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [215 kB]
Get:72 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libbind9-140 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [204 kB]
Get:73 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf liblwres141 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [210 kB]
Get:74 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf dbus-user-session all 1.10.22-0+deb9u1 [76.6 kB]
Get:75 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf dbus-x11 armhf 1.10.22-0+deb9u1 [87.8 kB]
Get:76 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf dbus armhf 1.10.22-0+deb9u1 [189 kB]
Get:77 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libdbus-1-3 armhf 1.10.22-0+deb9u1 [173 kB]
Get:78 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf ncurses-term all 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1 [469 kB]
Get:79 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf apt-transport-https armhf 1.4.8 [165 kB]
Get:80 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf curl armhf 7.52.1-5+deb9u1 [220 kB]
Get:81 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libcurl3 armhf 7.52.1-5+deb9u1 [261 kB]
Get:82 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 armhf 2.36.5-2+deb9u1 [152 kB]
Get:83 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common all 2.36.5-2+deb9u1 [310 kB]
Get:84 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 armhf 2.36.5-2+deb9u1 [15.3 kB]
Get:85 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libatspi2.0-0 armhf 2.22.0-6+deb9u1 [52.1 kB]
Get:86 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libavutil55 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [232 kB]
Get:87 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libswresample2 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [88.2 kB]
Get:88 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libavcodec57 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [4,152 kB]
Get:89 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libavformat57 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [867 kB]
Get:90 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libavresample3 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [80.3 kB]
Get:91 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpostproc54 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [72.8 kB]
Get:92 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libswscale4 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1 [161 kB]
Err:93 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libavfilter6 armhf 7:3.2.8-1~deb9u1
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:94 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libisc-export160 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [316 kB]
Get:97 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 armhf 2.16.6-0+deb9u1+rpi1 [1,726 kB]
Get:95 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libdns-export162 armhf 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u3 [764 kB]
Get:96 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 armhf 2.16.6-0+deb9u1+rpi1 [9,127 kB]
Get:98 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libnss3 armhf 2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1 [946 kB]
Get:99 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libruby2.3 armhf 2.3.3-1+deb9u1+rpi1 [2,865 kB]
Get:102 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-jwt all 1.4.2-1+deb9u1 [15.3 kB]
Get:103 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python3-jwt all 1.4.2-1+deb9u1 [15.3 kB]
Get:100 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libxfont2 armhf 1:2.0.1-3+deb9u1 [117 kB]
Get:101 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf linux-libc-dev armhf 4.9.51-1+rpi3 [1,261 kB]
Get:104 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf ruby2.3 armhf 2.3.3-1+deb9u1+rpi1 [187 kB]
Err:105 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf wpasupplicant armhf 2:2.4-1+deb9u1
  Connection failed [IP: 163.22.3.70 80]
Get:106 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf xkb-data all 2.19-1+deb9u1 [650 kB]
Fetched 137 MB in 19min 43s (115 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.15-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/libwbclient0_4.5.12+dfsg-2_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/ui/r/rpi-chromium-mods/rpi-chromium-mods_20171017_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.230 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-agent_2.1.18-8~deb9u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter6_3.2.8-1~deb9u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/b/bluez/libbluetooth3_5.43-2+rpt1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/realvnc-vnc/realvnc-vnc-server_6.2.0.29523_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.4-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 163.22.3.70 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried changing the DNS server to Google's (8.8.8.8) on both my router and the nameserver in resolv.conf in /etc/ folder since I found someone had an issue with connection fail to repository but it was on Raspbian Jessie and only on sudo apt-get update. But anyway, it didn't work for me :(

I am doing this all on my own and no one to teach or clarify my doubts. So sorry in advance if this was some silly thing!